# Calling window opened javascript function

Tags: javascript

This is a common problem related to cross-origin.
I have a Page base.html with `window.open('foo.html')` and foo.html with a JavaScript function called `faa()`.

base.html and foo.html are in the same domain (in this example, in the same directory too).

Have a look at this code:

```
<script>
        var opened_foo;

        $('#openfoo').click(function() {
            opened_foo= window.open('foo.html','_blank');
        });

        $('#dofaa').click(function() {
            opened_foo.faa("hello");        
        });
    </script>
```

The command `opened_foo` produced an error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

The error is pretty simple. My base.html seems to not have an "origin". But why? What do I need to do?

Comment: "base.html and foo.html are in them same domain" — They error message is that the origin is `null` which implies they are not on the same domain … or any domain at all, but you are loading local files.

Comment: Yeah! Seems loading file locally is not considered "same domain". Using apache to load the two html pages, resolve the problem. Thank you.